# Convert selected files in directory into another format

Tags: python, file, directory

For all the files in the input directory ending with "hic", I want to convert them to cool format. A single file can be converted using:

```
hic2cool_convert(<infile>, <outfile>)
```

But I'm not sure how to write a for loop to convert all the relevant files.

```
indir = "./others/"
outdir = "output/"

for file in os.listdir(indir + "*hic"):
   with open(os.path.join(indir + "*hic", file), "r") as f: # open in readonly mode
      hic2cool_convert(f, outdir + "f")
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 for file in os.listdir(indir + "*hic"):
      2    with open(os.path.join(indir + "*hic", file), "r") as f: # open in readonly mode
      3       hic2cool_convert(f, outdir + "f")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './others/*hic'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `os` has implemented shell wildcards like `'*hic'`. I recommend using `Path`, which is a lot easier to use than the `os` functions and also implements wildcard-capable `glob()`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path("others").glob("*hic"):
    with open(path) as f:
        pass # whatever you wanted to do
```

Comment: I tried `for path in Path(indir).glob("*hic"):
    with open(path) as f:
        hic2cool_convert(f, outdir + "f")` but it raised `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper`

Comment: Pass in `path` instead, then. (Are you not familiar with how to deal with exceptions? Plenty of resources online like programming tutorials to teach you...)

Comment: I think the issue is with the `<outfile>`. I'm trying to convert and store all the files in the `outdir`, such that `abc.hic` -> `abc.cool` or `def.hic` -> `def.cool`.

Comment: I'm using this software https://github.com/4dn-dcic/hic2cool

Answer (score 0):

Base in your error the folder is not found / been created. You should check first the file path using python "exists" function.

```
import os.path

path = indir + "*hic"

if os.path.exists(indir + "*hic"):
  ... do stuff
else:
  os.mkdir(path)
  ... do stuff
```

Comment: The directory does exist

Comment: what file format you need ?

Comment: I want to convert `.hic` format to `.cool` format.

Comment: I'm using this software https://github.com/4dn-dcic/hic2cool

Comment: can you send the latest error given because I'm still confuse with the file not found. i want to see the output of conversion. because the documentation said it was 

hic2cool convert <infile> <outfile>

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [24], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 for file in os.listdir(indir + "*hic"):
      2    with open(os.path.join(indir + "*hic", file), "r") as f: # open in readonly mode
      3       hic2cool_convert(f, outdir + "f")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './others/*hic'`

Comment: can you try basic conversion first without looping ? try basic like this if it works

hic2cool_convert('my_hic.hic', 'my_cool.cool', 0)